# Wait until the modal was positioned

Tags: c#, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, selenium-grid

I have problems detecting that a modal is in position I am using

```
wait.Until(SeleniumExtras.WaitHelpers.ExpectedConditions.ElementToBeClickable((WEAsesor.BtnColumnas))).Click();
```

but the modal has an effect of going up until reaching its position the instruction detects when the modal is in the DOM but I cannot perform any action on the element since Not yet this position, do you have any idea how to solve this?

Comment: Welcome to SO! You should probably add some more code for context so we can help you better

Answer (score 0):

You can write *custom* wait implementations like so:

```
wait.Until(element => /* Do something with the element */);
```

So if you want to wait for a location, you should probably first wait (by hand) to see what is your desired location. For example:

```
int expectedLocationX = WEAsesor.BtnColumnas.Location.X;
int expectedLocationY = WEAsesor.BtnColumnas.Location.Y;
```

After you know the expected location of your element, write your wait:

```
/* you set whatever the X or Y is, in this example, 10 */
int expectedLocationX = 10; 
int expectedLocationY = 10; 
wait.Until(driver => 
{
    bool isXCorrect = WEAsesor.BtnColumnas.Position.X == expectedLocationX;
    bool isYCorrect = WEAsesor.BtnColumnas.Position.Y == expectedLocationY;

    /* This code will return *true* only if both the X and Y are correct.*/
    return isXCorrent && isYCorrect;
});
```

Essentially, the `wait.Until(driver => ...)` method says, "here, use the driver if you want, do your stuff, and return true when you want me to stop waiting. If you return false or null, I will keep running the `...` and wait until you return me a true or non-null.

So you are *telling* the `wait` object, to wait until your element is at the expected location.